# Select two classes inside of one complex selector

Tags: css

Given two long and complex selectors such as

```
.question-number td:first-child > span[...]
.question-text td:first-child > span[...]
```

Is there a way to merge the two such that the long suffix does not need to be repeated? Something like (though this is not valid CSS)

```
(.question-number | .question-text) td:first-child > span[...]
```

Comment: Take a look at `scss`. It might be offering what you are looking for.

Comment: I'd prefer a native-CSS solution, but scss might be fun to try out; thanks

Comment: you can use `@if` `@else` in scss and make placeholder, so your code not to be repeated

Comment: No, this isn't possible in CSS; the only way to simplify long selectors would be to apply an `id` or, if you have more than one element to select with the selector, a `class` to the relevant element(s).

Comment: @davidthomas That's actually the most reasonable solution - make a third class and apply it to both elements.

Answer (score 1):

In case you only have those two classes that contains the word *question* you can consider [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) like below:

```css
[class*=question] td:first-child>span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="anoher-class">
    <td><span>some text</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="question-number">
    <td><span>some text</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>some text</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="question-text">
    <td><span>some text</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That doesn't apply in my particular case, but this is an interesting idea. Too bad there doesn't seem to be an `in` operator for use on attribute selectors.

Comment: `[attribute*=content]` **is** the *in selector*.

Comment: @connexo I suppose I wasn't specific enough - I mean `in` in the SQL sense, i.e. `[attribute in ('question-number', 'question-text')]` - rather than a pattern match.

Comment: The `:is()` selector will be available eventually. It's in the CSS4 Selectors Working Draft. https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#matches-pseudo https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is